# Feeding Variables in new-aduser -path option in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-4.0

Here is the Command I am trying to work with:

```psh
New-ADUser -name "$firstName $lastName" -SamAccountName "$firstName.$lastName" -GivenName "$firstName" -Surname "$lastName" -DisplayName "$firstName $lastName" -Path "OU=Employees,OU=$Dpart,DC=OPR,DC=Local" -Enabled $true -AccountPassword $PWD -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -EmailAddress "$firstName.$lastName@opr.org"
```

The Error Message I get:

```
ObjectNotFound: (CN=FIRST LAST...DC=OPR,DC=Local:String)
```

Once I remove the `$Dpart` from the `-Path` the command fires off correctly, but does not place the person into the correct OU. The command is filtered before hand and matches the name inside AD of the sub OU.

How can I use a variable inside the path command? I know it's simple, but I am just starting off with powershell.

Comment: What is the value of `$Dpath`?

Comment: `$Dpart = '000_Management'` There is 6 different values $Dpart can be. and it is feed using a switch statement. $Dpart is also declared at the start with `$Dpart = ""`

Answer (score 1):

```
New-ADUser -name "$firstName $lastName" -SamAccountName "$firstName.$lastName" -GivenName "$firstName" -Surname "$lastName" -DisplayName "$firstName $lastName" -Path "OU=$Dpart,OU=Employees,DC=OPR,DC=Local" -Enabled $true -AccountPassword $PWD -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -EmailAddress "$firstName.$lastName@opr.org"
```

It was so obvious that a snake would have bit me...

Lowest level OU first, then each level up after that. So, `OU=$Dpart, OU=Employees`